# Conflict RC522 & Fingerprint VIA i2c pins on Raspberry Pi B

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, i2c, spi

Fingerprint is connected on Pin3 & Pin 5

RC522 connected on Pin 24,23..etc as standard tutorials

**Problem:**

On the same script, if comment the line:
id, text = reader.read()

the fingerprint works, if not the rfid reader works.

if i leave both as the following code, an error occurs:
[enter link description here](http://www.savetext.online/qfefeeqfef)

[image: Code]

**/boot/config.txt:**

dtparam=audio=on

dtoverlay=w1-gpio

enable_uart=1

dtparam=uart1=on

#dtparam=i2c

dtparam=spi=on

dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=10000

dtparam=i2s=on

dtparam=i2c0=on

dtparam=i2c1=on

dtparam=i2c=on

**gpio readall**
[image]

**Raspberry**
[image]
[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have connected the fingerprint via USB to UART convertor.
So no more conflict between fingerprint and RC522.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> Problem:
>
> On the same script, if comment the line: id, text = reader.read()
>
> the fingerprint works, if not the rfid reader works.

1. If both work one by one, the wiring should be fine, and ports should be enabled. The problem is most likely in your code, or the library you use.
2. Does the reader.read() do a single reading regardless of tag proximity or it keeps reading until it actually gets a reading? Cause the problem sounds a lot like it loops until it can return something...

Comment: even if i remove this line:
""id, text = reader.read()"" but keep this ""reader = SimpleMFRC522()"", it wont run

Comment: Then I don't know the answer. Sorry... :-/

Comment: No problem, thank you for trying indeed